# Riemann sum of infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, limits, riemann-sum

Let $f$ be a non-negative, bounded and continuous function such that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x < \infty$.
Does it hold that
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)
=
\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

### Current approach

Due to $f \geq 0$ we can use Fubini's theorem to show that
$$
 \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)
=
 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg).
$$
Thus, the question boils down to whether the Riemann sum converges when the function that is being integrated is an infinite series, i.e. does it hold that
$$
 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)
\rightarrow 
\int_0^1  \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f(j + x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

My current approach to show this looks as follows:
$$
\bigg\vert 
    \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)
    -
    \int_0^1  \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f(j + x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\bigg\vert
\leq
 \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigg\vert
    \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) 
    -
    \int_0^1 f(j + x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\bigg\vert
$$
Here, I can't figure out how to bound the absolute value such that the limit of the series converges to zero.

Comment: Take $f=1_{\mathbb Q}$ for a counterexample. Probably one has to add some regularity conditions on $f$.

Comment: That's a good point. I've added continuity to the assumptions on $f$.

Comment: I think it is unlikely.$$ \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$$ is of course OK, but I think we should be able to find an example where $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ fails.

Comment: I would have guessed that the function well-behaved enough for dominated convergence to be applicable. After all, the function is bounded, so it cannot explode on any compact set and it's integrable so it must go to zero at $\pm\infty$. But I still can't find a majorant :/

Comment: Isnt the expression (both LHS and RHS) we are trying to prove is lower bounded by Lower Riemann sum and upper bounded by Upper Riemann sum and since u r assuming the function is Riemann integrable and integrate to finite value, isnt what we are trying to prove is true by Sandwitch theorem since Lower and Upper Riemann sum converges to integral and the LHS of the given expression. Are u saying Lebesgue integrable to fintie value in the question ? So are u asking whether under these conditions Lebesgue integrability is equivalent to Riemann integrability ? If so, pls edit question.Thanks man.

Comment: Upper and lower bound by corresponding Riemann sums should only be true all the time if $f$ were monotonic. Thus, we cannot use sandwich theorem or am I missing something?

Comment: Under monotonicity (say on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$) see this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2964219/121671) on general, it dow not hold. use functions that oscillate *a lot*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f$ (continuous nonnegative integrable) like this.  Let $f(x) = 0$ on $(-\infty,1]$.
For each $m \in \mathbb N$, on the interval $[m,m+1]$ the function has
$f\left(m+\frac{k}{m}\right) = 1$ for $k=1,2,\dots,m-1$,
$f(m)= f(m+1) = 0$,
$0\le f(x) \le 1$,
$\int_m^{m+1} f = \frac{1}{m^2}$.

For example, on $[4,5]$ it could look like this:  [image]
where the three triangles have height $1$ and width $1/24$.

Let
$$
S_n = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) .
$$
We claim $S_n$ does not converge to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$.
Choose $j_1 \in \mathbb N$ so that
$$
\sum_{j=j_1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2} < \frac14
\quad\text{and thus}\quad
\int_{j_1}^\infty f < \frac14 .
$$
Then choose $n_1 \ge 4$ so that, for each $j$ with $1 \le j \le j_1$,
and for each $n \ge n_1$,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(j+\frac{k}{n}\right) - \int_{j}^{j+1} f\right| < \frac{1}{4j_1} 
\quad\text{and thus} \quad
\sum_{j=1}^{j_1} \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(j+\frac{k}{n}\right) - \int_{j}^{j+1} f\right| < \frac{1}{4}.
$$
We claim that, for all $n > n_1$, we have
$$
\left|S_n - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f\right| > \frac{1}{4}
$$
[and thus $S_n$ does not converge to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f$].
To prove this:  Fix $n > n_1$.  Then
$$
S_n = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) = A_n+B_n,\quad\text{where}\\
A_n=\sum_{j=1}^{j_1}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg)\\
B_n=\sum_{j=j_1+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) .
$$

Compute:
\begin{align}
A_n - \int_1^{j_1+1} f
&=
\sum_{j=1}^{j_1}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(j + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) - \int_j^{j+1} f\right]
\\ &
\ge -\sum_{j=1}^{j_1} \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(j+\frac{k}{n}\right) - \int_{j}^{j+1} f\right| 
> -\frac{1}{4} ,
\\
B_n& \ge
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n f\bigg(n + \frac{k}{n} \bigg) 
=\frac{n-1}{n} \ge \frac34 ,
\\
- \int_{j_1+1}^\infty f & \ge - \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}
Add to get
$$
S_n - \int_1^\infty f > \frac14 .
$$